# Rails: Using Devise So User Can Only See Their Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to rails and practicing by building a simple "reminders" application.

I'm now using Devise to add user authentication. Once a user logs in, they are redirected to the index page of the application. At this point, I would like the user to only be able to see the reminders they have created.

reminders_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @reminders = current_user.reminders
    @reminder = current_user.reminders.new #Show create form on index
  end
 def new
    @reminder = current_user.reminders.new
  end

 def create
 @reminder = Reminder.new(reminder_params)

 respond_to do |format|
      if @reminder.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reminder, notice: 'Reminder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @reminder }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @reminder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
 end
```

At this point, the code runs and displays without errors, however, it doesn't show any reminders on the index page. When I create a new reminder, it successfully creates the reminder, however, it doesn't display it on the index page.

Here are my models:

models/user.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reminders
 end
```

models/reminders.rb

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Schema.rb

```
  create_table "reminders", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "medication"
    t.time     "time"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

index.html.rb

```
<h1>Current Reminders</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Medication</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @reminders.each do |reminder| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= reminder.medication %></td>
        <td><%= reminder.time %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to 'Remove', reminder, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Create New Reminder</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

What do I need to do so a user can only view their reminders on the index page? I think I'm going in the right direction, just can't nail it down. Would something like CanCan help?

Comment: You can use cancan but I think its not necessary, because when u say current_user.remainders, it shows the remainders of the user who i currently logged in. Did you try logging in from two browsers and see if the logic is working?

Comment: Everything appears to be working. However, it doesn't display any reminders for specific users. Reminders.all still works fine however.

Comment: changed this @reminder = Reminder.new to current_user.remainders.new ?

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. This is a real head scratcher.

Comment: but where is your create action?. U need to save your reminder object

Comment: be specific about any kind of error messages, look into the database if the entries have a user_id.

Comment: @reminder = Reminder.new(reminder_params) should again be current_user.remainders.new

Comment: Added create action to the original post. No errors at this point. It just isn't showing any reminders when the controller is set to     @reminders = current_user.reminders.

Comment: @argentum47 - I gave that a shot. Now I get an error about the field being blank when submitting the form, even though the field clearly isn't blank. It must not be picking up the data in the form?

Edit - GOT IT! I needed to keep the (reminders_params) on that line as well.

Comment: which field is blank? try to check if the params hash that is going as a post request which should be like :user => {... :remainder => {} } is permitted in your controller and both of'em matches..

Comment: and you need a @remainder.save after the new in your create. I have never  seen it in the respond_to part. I dunno if your record is created, if it is then its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @argentum47 for the answer in the comments.

```
def create
 @reminder = Reminder.new(reminder_params)
```

Needed to be:

```
def create
 @reminder = current_user.reminders.new(reminder_params)
```